# RxJava 2: Replacement for Subject<T,R>

Tags: rx-java2

In RxJava 1.x it was possible to do a `T -> R` conversion in a `Subject`. For example the input type could be a `Integer` and the output type could still be a `String`. In RxJava 2.0 this option has been removed, now it's just `Subject<T>` instead of `Subject<T,R>`. This change is also mentioned in the [What's different in 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subjects-and-processors) document on the RxJava wiki, but unfortunately no replacement is given. Is there any apart from declaring the `Subject` as `Subject<Object>`?

Comment: Did you create your own custom Subjects before? We haven't seen any use for Subject<T, R> as it requires custom Subject implementation which is an advanced topic.

Comment: @akarnokd Not before because I'm converting old code with chained callbacks to Rx. One callback (now Observable) delivers byte arrays that are streamed to a webservice that does return chunked text after some time and there's no 1:1 correlation between the number of byte arrays and the number of returned strings. It's not a problem to convert text into byte arrays but it's also not pretty.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to split the input and output points:

```
Subject<T> input = ...;
Observable<R> output = input.map(...);
```

Previous uses of the subject can be directed at `output` while the input gets redirected through `input`.